# Visual Studio - File List element

Tags: visual-studio

So I'm trying to make a simple program with a file list and I wanted to know if Visual Studio has a file list element like the one from `explorer.exe` or the `Open/Save File Dialog`.

Like this: http://gyazo.com/c2439238f4d42ffe54b29f116aea579e

Comment: Yes you may use this one as reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426832/open-file-from-a-listbox.

Comment: Yeah, i thought of that, but the problem is that i wanted something kinda fancy, with icons and etc... but i think i'll end up using ListBoxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use various methods with the ListBoxes to make this happen. For example, save icon images for different kinds of file extensions and call them if the file extension matched on the existing files from the listbox.